# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I am attempting to statically link GLEW to Visual Studio 2017. I followed a video tutorial exactly, but I still got an error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory

I have no idea what could be causing it. Here are the steps I took to link GLEW:

1. Put the folder named GLEW into a folder called dependencies in the solution directory
2. Went to C/C++, General and under "Additional Include Directories," I added $(SolutionDir)Dependencies\GLEW\include, which, when I go to edit, evaluates to the correct path
3. Went to Linker, General and under "Additional Library Directories," I added $(SolutionDir)Dependencies\GLEW\lib\Release\Win32, which also evaluates to the correct path
4. Went to Linker, Input and under "Additional Dependencies," I added glew32s.lib
5. Finally, I went to C/C++, Preprocessor and under "Preprocessor Definitions," I added GLEW_STATIC

I also did this same process with GLFW, and it worked perfectly, so I have no idea what the problem could be. I have checked and doublechecked the paths, so I am fairly certain that they are correct. Thank you in advance!

Comment: ***I have no idea what could be causing it*** You don't have the folder that contains the GL folder in any of the folders your compile searches in its include path.

Comment: `$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\GLEW\include` Did you verify that this folder exists? Is there a GL folder inside that?

Comment: It does exist and it does contain a GL folder

Comment: Is there a `glew.h` file in that folder. The compiler is saying that there is not. Possibly did you edit the wrong configuration? Settings for each configuration (Debug, Release ...) are independent

Comment: yes, there is a glew.h file in that folder. And also yes, I have edited it for all configurations.

Comment: This really is the only option. Maybe you have a space in the path or missing a `;` between paths.

Comment: I had the same issue and I resolved it by building glew in my system, however I wouldn't put that as an answer as it just seems wrong, because my investigation concluded 32bit vs 64bit conflict. Like I said that might not be the reason so I am not putting it as an answer but hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

When you should be doing

```
#include <glew.h>
```

Is glew.h directly in the win32 folder? Or is there a further "GL" folder?